# Property 'push' does not exist on type in ValueList Dropdown

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Hai am developing android and ios application using native script-angular.I have used a nativescript-drop-down plugin in my app.I have used valuelist array to plot values in the dropdown. But the value list return error like "Property 'push' does not exist on type in ValueList Dropdown".I don't know how this issue arises. Help me to fix the issue.

My Sample code:

My Html:

```
<StackLayout orientation="vertical">
    <DropDown [items>="items"></DropDown>   
</StackLayout>
```

My Component ts file:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import {ValueList} from "nativescript-drop-down";


@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl:"app.component.html",
})

export class AppComponent {
    public items:ValueList<string>;

        constructor() {
        this.items = [];
         for(var k=0; k<10; k++)
        {
            items.push({
                value:k,
                display:"Hello World"
            })
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Can you share some code? Is it a TypeScript compile time error?

Comment: Hai manoj i have shared my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

you are doing assigning array which is not ValueList bype where as items variable is. So I guess that's what causing the issue.

Consider below code which is mentioned like in the [`Documentation`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-drop-down#working-with-value-and-display-members).

```
   public items: ValueList<string>;

   constructor() {
      let valueItems = [];

      for(var k=0; k<10; k++) {
         valueItems.push({
             value:k,
             display:"Hello World"
         });
      }

     this.items = new ValueList<string>(valueItems);

}
```

I think you have a typo in Template code..

```
<StackLayout orientation="vertical">
    <DropDown [items]="items"></DropDown>   
</StackLayout>
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Okay thank you it was working.but splice property and length property also shows an error like "Property 'splice or length' does not exist on type in ValueList Dropdown" .i can't understand why this error happen?

Comment: you might need to add string for `value` property in `valueItems` instead number...

Comment: I added string value in my project but it  was not worked.

Comment: Actually as per docs we need to add length for custom object entries.. I have not worked with this till now.. So i have limited understanding about this. You can did this by reading docs well I guess.

Comment: Consider up vote and mark it as answer if it helps you out from initial problem. :)

Comment: can you share the document

Comment: you can see the above docs which linked with answer or you can also check with git repo link.. https://github.com/peterstaev/nativescript-drop-down